# opposite to thresh in pandas dropna

Tags: pandas, rows

I want to delete rows in my Dataframe that have more than 9 columns as NaN.

The thresh argument does exactly the opposite.

Is there any option to do this wihtout creating a new dataframe or without iterating over rows?

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```py
df[df.isna().sum(axis=1) < 9]
```